# d3: search input to return nested data value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 bubble chart showing names by count. I am trying to add an input box so a user can search for a particular name to highlight the corresponding bubble, as well as show the name and count as a text. I nested the data by name, but now I don't seem to be able to access the count value in the nested data, so when a name is entered in the input box, it only returns the key and the count is "undefined". [Here](http://codepen.io/kaz-a/pen/BKxWyR?editors=0010)'s the code. And this is where I'm having a problem:

```
d3.select("#userInput").on("keyup", search);

function search(value, d) {
    var input = this.value.toUpperCase();
    var name = d.key;
    var name = input;

    var count = d.Count;

    circles.classed("circle-hover", function(d) {
      return name == d.Name;
    });

    d3.select("#text").html("<h2>" + name + "</h2><br /><h4>" + count + " names found</h4>");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function search(value, d) {
    var input = this.value.toUpperCase();
    var count = 0;
    var element = svg.selectAll(".circle")
    .filter(function(d){ return d.Name === input})
    .each(function(d, i){
     count += d.Count;
    });
    var name = input;

    var self = d3.select(this),
    rects = d3.selectAll(".symbols>div>svg>circle");

    rects.each(function(){
        var r = d3.select(this);
        if (r.style("stroke") === self.style("stroke")){
            r.style({ "stroke": "red", "stroke-width": "3px" });
        }
    });

    circles.classed("circle-hover", function(d) {
      return name == d.Name;
  });

    d3.select("#text").html("<h2>" + name + "</h2><br /><h4>" + count + " names found</h4>");

};
```